# setColorFilter not working on Android 5.0

Tags: android, button

I'm using setColorFilter in my app to change the background colour of a button.

Here is my code :

```
// layout_main.xml
...
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_round"
    android:text="button"/>
     ...
```

====================================================

```
// btn_round.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">   
  <solid android:name="solid" android:color="#000000"/>
  <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
     android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
  </shape>
```

====================================================

```
//MainActivity.java
...
Button btn_search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_serach);
btn_search.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

I tried Mode.MULTIPLY and Mode.OVERLAY and the result is:

[image]

I expected to have the effect of ColorFilter but it seems it's hidden behind the button.

This code worked well on Android 4.4. But when I try on Android 5.0, it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you use white (#fff) as your solid colour in the drawable?

Comment: Wow It's work! Really Thank you, FunktheMonk!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_round);
background.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
btn_search .setBackground(background); // Use setBackgroundDrawable for API<16
btn_search .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: hey, i just posted a question asking about color filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68881601/how-to-setcolorfilter-to-a-png-image please help ...thanks,