# How to setColorFilter to a png image

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am already using setColorFilter() to add color to these lines. The original color for this line is yellow. I use red or green depend on some statement.

This is what I have so far:
Someone helped me to do this:
[How to set filter property in ImageView Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410582/how-to-set-filter-property-in-imageview-android-studio)

[image]

But now I need to add color under the line...like this:

[image]

```
sparkline.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
sparkline.setImageResource(R.drawable.btc_spike);
```

---

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/sparkline"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                app:saturation="80"
                app:brightness="0.85"
                app:crossfade="0.0"
                app:warmth="10"
                android:src="@drawable/btc_spike" />
```

I also found this page but not sure if it wants me to add another image on top of this or something else...

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode#MULTIPLY

Comment: To achieve this, you have to create custom view and draw the shadows after creating the graph path. If creating the custom graph is not your use-case then you can checkout this library - https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: this is a png ..that is coming from a link

Comment: The original image is yellow...and I use color to make it red or green...do you think there is something like shadow or something to add to these images?

Comment: Can you provide the image link or the image, so that we can test?

Comment: Suree.....here is... https://s3.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1.png

Comment: @ChhatrasalSinghBundela you can save as...Again...The image is a png yellow line..and I am available to change the color..to red or green..but I would like to use that shadow..I will also "start a bounty" right now! Thanks

Comment: @ChhatrasalSinghBundela please let me know if it help..my app really need this image like that to look super cool hhehehh thank for your help!

Comment: Are all the graphs continuous? No holes or breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a color under the line using the png image you can do something like below:

1. Retrieve the png image as a Bitmap (source Bitmap).
2. Copy the source Bitmap in a temporary Bitmap (output Bitmap).
3. Iterate each x,y pixel of the output Bitmap and find the Line pixels (Non-Transparent pixels). The remaining Transparent pixels distinguish them to Transparent pixels above the line area and below the line area.
4. Finally set the Red/Green color to the line pixels and the Red/Green light color to the Transparent pixels below the line.

Here is a helper function which does the above steps:

```
public static Bitmap getShadowLineBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap srcBitmap, @ColorInt int lineColor, @ColorInt int shadowUnderLineColor){

        //copy the srcBitmap to the outBitmap
        Bitmap outBitmap = srcBitmap.copy(srcBitmap.getConfig(), true);
        try
        {
            //iterate each x,y pixel
            for (int x = 0; x < outBitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
                boolean foundLinePx = false;
                for (int y = 0; y < outBitmap.getHeight(); y++) {

                    //get the current RGBA x,y pixel
                    int rgba = outBitmap.getPixel(x, y);

                    //if its a Transparent pixel it means that is a pixel above or below the line
                    //so draw the pixels above the line to Transparent and draw the pixels below the line to a red/green light color
                    if (rgba == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        if(foundLinePx)
                            outBitmap.setPixel(x, y, shadowUnderLineColor);
                        else
                            outBitmap.setPixel(x, y, rgba);
                    }
                    //if its a Non-Transparent pixel it means that is a line pixel so draw each line pixel to red/green
                    else {
                        outBitmap.setPixel(x, y, lineColor);
                        foundLinePx = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return outBitmap;
    }
```

And can be used like below:

```
//get the src Bitmap from Resources (Bitmap can be retrieved also from Glide/Picasso)
Bitmap srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sparkline); 

//Draw the Bitmap with Green Line Color and Green Shadow Light Color
imageView.setImageBitmap(getShadowLineBitmap(srcBitmap, Color.argb(255, 25, 189, 119), Color.argb(255, 231, 250, 243)));

//Draw the Bitmap with Red Line Color and Red Shadow Light Color
imageView.setImageBitmap(getShadowLineBitmap(srcBitmap, Color.argb(255, 228, 112, 117), Color.argb(255, 252, 227, 228)));
```

**Result:**

[image: green]
[image: red]

**Load Bitmaps using Glide in RecyclerView**

I have tested some graph image links from your domain (eg: https://s3.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1.png) with a RecyclerView and it works as expected even if i scrolled the cells up/down.

In on `void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)` add the below lines of code to load the bitmap using Glide (Glide Version: com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0):

```
Glide.with(itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext())
        .asBitmap()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholer)
        .error(R.drawable.error)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .override(164, 48) //we know the web image size (164x48)
        .load(url)
        .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(164, 48)
        {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
               
                        //set resource to ImageBitmap
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);

                        //set Green Color filter to line and Green Shadow line colour in AsyncTask
                        if(isGreen) {
                            imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 25, 189, 119), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            new DrawBitmapShadowAsyncTask(imageView,
                                    Color.argb(255, 25, 189, 119),
                                    Color.argb(255, 231, 250, 243))
                                    .execute(resource);
                        }
                        //set Red Color filter to line and Red Shadow line colour in AsyncTask
                        else{
                            imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 228, 112, 117), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            new DrawBitmapShadowAsyncTask(imageView,
                                    Color.argb(255, 228, 112, 117),
                                    Color.argb(255, 252, 227, 228))
                                    .execute(resource);
                        }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadStarted(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                if(placeholder!=null){
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
                else {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(itemView.getResources(), R.drawable.placeholer));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                if(errorDrawable!=null){
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
                }
                else {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(itemView.getResources(), R.drawable.error));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

            }
        });
```

From above:

1. The `void onLoadStarted(@Nullable Drawable placeholder)` sets the ImageView placeholder drawable when a load is started.
2. The `void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable)` sets the ImageView error drawable when a load fails.
3. The `void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition)` called when the resource load has finished and the Bitmap is ready to be used. In this callback we use the previous helper function in AsyncTask to draw with light color under the graph line.

Below is the `DrawBitmapShadowAsyncTask` AsyncTask private static class inside RecyclerView Adapter used from `Glide onResourceReady` to draw the shadow color under the line in the Background Thread:

```
    /**
     * Draws Shadow Color under the Graph line asynchronously
     */
    private static class DrawBitmapShadowAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {

        private WeakReference<ImageView> imageView = null;
        private @ColorInt int lineColor;
        private @ColorInt int shadowUnderLineColor;

        private DrawBitmapShadowAsyncTask(ImageView imageView, @ColorInt int lineColor, @ColorInt int shadowUnderLineColor){
            this.imageView = new WeakReference<>(imageView);
            this.lineColor = lineColor;
            this.shadowUnderLineColor = shadowUnderLineColor;
        }

        /**
         * Colorize the srcBitmap below the graph line in a Background Thread
         * @param bitmaps bitmaps[0] (srcBitmap)
         * @return the output bitmap
         */
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
            return getShadowLineBitmap(bitmaps[0], lineColor, shadowUnderLineColor);
        }

        /**
         * Set the output Bitmap to imageView in Main Thread
         * @param bitmap the output bitmap
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(imageView!=null && imageView.get()!=null){
                imageView.get().clearColorFilter();
                imageView.get().setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Helper method to draw shadow color under the line
         * @param srcBitmap The source Bitmap
         * @param lineColor The color line
         * @param shadowUnderLineColor The shadow color under the line
         * @return Bitmap The output Bitmap
         */
        private Bitmap getShadowLineBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap srcBitmap, @ColorInt int lineColor, @ColorInt int shadowUnderLineColor){

            //copy the srcBitmap to the outBitmap
            Bitmap outBitmap = srcBitmap.copy(srcBitmap.getConfig(), true);
            try
            {
                //iterate each x,y pixel
                for (int x = 0; x < outBitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
                    boolean foundLinePx = false;
                    for (int y = 0; y < outBitmap.getHeight(); y++) {

                        //get the current RGBA x,y pixel
                        int rgba = outBitmap.getPixel(x, y);

                        //if its a Transparent pixel it means that is a pixel above or below the line
                        //so draw the pixels above the line to Transparent and draw the pixels below the line to a red/green light color
                        if (rgba == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                            if(foundLinePx)
                                outBitmap.setPixel(x, y, shadowUnderLineColor);
                            else
                                outBitmap.setPixel(x, y, rgba);
                        }
                        //if its a Non-Transparent pixel it means that is a line pixel so draw each line pixel to red/green
                        else {
                            outBitmap.setPixel(x, y, lineColor);
                            foundLinePx = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            return outBitmap;
        }
    }
```

**RecyclerView Results:**

[image: recyclerview_red]
[image: recyclerview_green]

Comment: THankkkk youuu...!! Yes im using glide...Im trying to implement your code in my glide

Comment: Yes it works! The only problem is that I am displaying this image in a `RecycleView` so, if I scroll down and then I scroll up again the images are gone and it doesn't come back...any way to fix it? And let me know how can I buy you some coffee!! jejeje 
...I can also try the graph (if you think it will better) but I might have to need your help for that..

Comment: You are welcome @Maduro. Glad to help ;) I have updated my answer to give an example of how you can use the above helper function with a Glide in RecyclerView. Let me know if you still have this issue when you scroll up and down.

Comment: AWESOME! thanks, I already uploaded my app to the Google play..but this is gonna be part of the next update!! i will implement it in a few hours...I have a question..but I will create a new question for that but is something about calling almost 5,000 items from y sql database. Right now its working but slow. Im loading 200 items (onScroll)...I will create a new question to provide more details ...and let me know how to buy you some coffee! or if you selling a course or any type of support I could provide to you...

Comment: Hi @Maduro i have updated my answer to draw the graph line on a background Thread using an AsyncTask when the bitmap is ready to be used from Glide onResourceReady. This is a better solution if you have a lot of images loaded in the RecyclerView. Also i have set the diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) in case your images are changing very frequently. You can change this based on your needs. Yes about the new issue its better to open a new question for this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. it works but for some reason..the line and shadow are black. Sometime is black and sometime is green or red. But, most of the time is black. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi @Maduro what Glide version are you using? I have tested this on two different android devices with Glide com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0 and  i didn’t get any black colour. Another option is to try to change the diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) to diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE). If nothing works try to upload a minimal reproducible example of your code with the issue on Github to check if you are missing something else.

Comment: Im using `implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0"` it looks like it will work but sometimes images are black and grey ...unless I set the `                            sparkline.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 228, 112, 117), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`

Comment: Hi @Maduro check updated answer i hope now you will not see any black color. I have changed the onResourceReady() by setting the image Bitmap first and then i am using the imageView.setColorFilter() to change the color line before starting the new DrawBitmapShadowAsyncTask. Also i have added in DrawBitmapShadowAsyncTask in onPostExecute the clearColorFilter() before setting the new shadow line Bitmap to imageView.